# SVN hook pre commit hook to prevent addition of same filename

Tags: php, bash, svn, svn-hooks

I have list of classes in my repository and i don't want same class names to be added twice.
My aim is to prevent commit of same file names i.e. if abc.class.php already exists in any directory, user can't add abc.class.php to repository.

I tried

```
CHANGED=`$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep "^[A]" | $AWK '{print $2}' | grep \.class.php$`
for FILENAME in $CHANGED
do  
    AlreadyFoundFile=$(locate $FILENAME ./var/www/html/REPO/)

    if [ $AlreadyFoundFile ]
    then
        echo "WARNING-  "$FILENAME" - class name already exist" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

it is checking committed files in /var/www/html/REPO/ (checkedOut Branch) but i want to check for files in Repository.
Is there a possible method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `svnlook tree`:

```
CHANGED=`$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep "^[A]" | $AWK '{print $2}' | grep \.class.php$`
tree=$( svnlook tree "$REPOS" )

for FILENAME in $CHANGED
do  
    if grep -q "$FILENAME" <<< "$tree"
    then
        echo "WARNING-  "$FILENAME" - class name already exist" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Note that this will not be limited to a certain branch. If you need that, the tree command allows specifying a path as a second argument, see the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.c.tree.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, got a direction but grep command is giving error - Syntax error: redirection unexpected, searched about this error and added #!/bin/bash at top, still getting error

Comment: Worked thanks, adding #!/bin/bash at top resolved issue